# Weblogic connection pool

Tags: weblogic9.x

Whenever I change connection pool parameters (url, id, pwd etc) I try to deploy the new connection pool in weblogic using the Control tab. I do a shutdown and start which IMO should redepoly the new connection pool.
But the changes take effect only when I restart the server. What other parameters need to be tuned to avoid restarting the server?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to untarget and retarget that specific connection pool to the server or cluster, that should be enough.

You dont have to restart the whole WL server.

Answer (score 0):

Some settings require reset (or redeploy) and some don't.

To find out which option requires restart/redeploy you should click on [*More info ...*] near option description (or go to
**JDBC Data Source -> Configuration -> Connection Pool**)

In example, you will find out that ***Maximum Capacity*** does not require restart.
But for ***Pinned-To-Thread*** option it says:

> Changes take effect after you redeploy the module or restart the server.